# Photo library will not fully upload to iCloud from computer

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I'm trying to upload my entire photo library to iCloud before my computer completely breaks down. There have been internet connection issues (among other problems) and I'm trying to back up my photos to the cloud before I restore the computer to its factory settings. I already backed everything up with time machine, but I would like to back it up to the cloud as well because I've had issues with time machine as well.

Of the 15,000 photos I have, only 2,000 are uploaded to iCloud. I tried to sync everything months ago, and it still won't upload any more photos. I have plenty of storage on iCloud, so that isn't the problem. I tried the upload multiple times while the Internet was working fine as well.

In iPhoto (on my Mac) and under preferences -> iCloud settings, I selected "iCloud photo library" (says it will automatically upload and store my entire library in iCloud to access photos and videos from all my apple devices or on the web). Just below it says "uploading 12,809 items" with a bar below that shows no progress on the upload is being made. Again, this option was selected months ago, so there is some issue that I don't know how to fix.

I have tried to manually upload the photos through iCloud.com, but it won't work either. I'm obviously not very computer savvy, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I know it may be a little too late to answer but, if you haven't found out a way to get all of your photos to your ICloud, here I how:

You must transfer all photos from PC to Iphone through ITunes.  You should have a photos tab that you can select after connecting phone to pc.  You must check the box that say sync photos and make sure you select the radio button where you can pick which folders you want transferred over.  Unless you want your WHOLE library.  After you sync your photos, create a new album on your phone and SAVE those photos to it.

Icloud photo library will only upload photos that were TAKEN or SAVED to the phone.  Once you save your photos, go ahead and use icloud photo library to upload those photos to Icloud.  To view among all devices, make sure Upload to My Photo Stream is on.  If you want to share photos, make sure ICloud Photo Sharing is on.

Im a Technical Lead for a well known cellular company and have done my own research, troubleshooting, and testing to confirm this information.